# Configure TFS 2015 GIT Clone URL to use a DNS alias

Tags: tfs-2015

Is there a way to configure TFS 2015 Update1, so that the **Git clone URL** it displays in the web portal is a DNS alias of our choosing?

Right now it is using the server's actual name but our IT department usually has us connect to TFS via an alias like tfs-org.is.acme.com instead of the server's physical name like tfs1.is.acme.com.  This facilitates future migrations where they can move a collection to a new machine (usually when upgrading to a major version of TFS) and then change just the alias and not impact every developer's "origin" URL (or workspace config).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to this URL.You can't edit this link, this is based on the TFS server url.
[image]

Unless you'd like to edit the TFS server url to meet your needs. However, if you want to edit the server url and use https, there are also many limitations. More info from MSDN: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833872(v=vs.120).aspx